# Failed to connect remote jupyter notebook

Tags: ssh, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to run a jupyter notebook on remote remote machine `user@remote`  and use it from my local machine.  I did

```
local@host  $ ssh user@remote
password for user@remote: *******
user@remote $ ipython notebook --no-browser --port=8889
```

On my local machine then I do

```
local@host  $ ssh -N -L localhost:8888:localhost:8889 user@remote
password for user@remote: *******
```

when I open this(`localhost:8888`) in my browser it says

```
local@host  $ channel 2: open failed: connect failed: Connection refused
```

Answer (score 1):

Try changing in your command from

`localhost:8888:localhost:8889`

to

`8888:localhost:8889`.

Comment: Why do you think this would help?

Comment: Because that's what worked for me....